# Eagle: What is the significance of the tCream layer having this "hashed" pattern?

Tags: eaglecad

I am trying to modify a part because in the original libary, some of the pads were of differing sizes. I would like to make all pads to be of the same size. In the following image, there are three pads. The first and third pads are in the original form.

In the middle pad, you can see that I lengthened one of the shorter pads with the polygon tool, but the polygon I get is solid.

By process of elimination (removing layers from view in the Layer Settings menu) I have found out that the these pads are in the tCream layer.

What is the meaning for the diagonal "hash" lines? Why does my polygon not have those lines, even though I'm drawing on the same layer?

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the tCream layer is used for generating stencils for the top layer.  The purpose of the pattern is just to differentiate it from other layers.

Comment: @Funkyguy That does sound right, from what I've read. Do you know why my polygon is solid?

Comment: You can select the specific pattern you have in the layers menu if you double-click on the little colored box in between the layer number and layer name.  In that you'll see a thing called "fillsyle", it looks like you have the solid one selected.

Comment: From your tip, I have verified that the fillstyle is "cross hashed", but the polygons are still showing up solid. Maybe a bug in Eagle 7.2? Either way, it seems like mechanically it won't make a difference. I couldn't find this info on the web, so thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: No problem!  
Hmm its odd that it is still solid though.  You might want to let cadsoft know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no significance; if you double-click the layer button or use the "display" command you can change the colour and display fill style for each of the layers. It's only for being able to visually differentiate the layers on your screen; they all print the same.

Comment: Exactly!  As stated in the comments